# Protect the question "Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?"

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

[Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

There have been a few low quality answers added, one such was added less than 30 minutes ago. Shouldn't this question be protected?

Comment: Note that you can do this by using a custom moderator flag; you don't have to post on Meta. Just be sure you're clear on why you feel it should be protected.

Answer (score -1):

[That answer was the only answer added in almost a year.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6219454/timeline)

Based on the current guidelines for [protecting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/175248) - that is, a question should be protected if it's attracting a *lot* of spam from new users, I'm not sure that protection is warranted here.

I will note that it *has* been protected now, but I'm not convinced that this is necessary.  There really hasn't been enough traffic on it to justify it.  Downvoting/deleting the question would've been sufficient if it were *truly* unsuitable for the site.

Comment: The post has gotten like half a dozen bad answers from users that wouldn't have been able to post if it were protected.  Sure, only one of them was recent, but it *does* indicate a pattern of low quality contributions from new users over time, and it's not like it costs much to protect the question

Comment: @Servy:  There were *no* negatively voted answers all of last year; the most recent one comes in around December '15.  With the new answer now being deleted, there are a grand total of *four* answers out of 22 that were "poor".  I get that you may have reservations over the answers' quality, but I'm not seeing this rise to the occasion of *needing* protection.

Comment: Again, I agreed with you that only one of the bad answers were recent, (although the second most recent bad answer was around one year ago, not two, but still, not recent).  It's not so much that this question is going to become completely flooded with crap overnight if not protected, but rather that protecting it will, at least moderately, improve the usefulness of the question/answers by having it attract a few less bad answers over the years.  So sure, it doesn't *need* it, but it can still benefit from it.

Comment: @Servy:  I think I'll agree to disagree here.  I remain unconvinced that protection is necessary.

Comment: I specifically said in my comment that it *isn't* necessary.  What it would be is helpful.  There are lots of things that "aren't necessary" that are still worth doing.